# V-Show directive function infinite loop

Tags: vuejs2

I´m calling a function inside a v-if directive to hide links in the sidebar according to the user role. 
As the user is being retrieved from the remote database asynchronously, it happens that sometimes the user info, inside the getUser() function will return null, therefore I thought of set a timeout of some seconds to wait for the user info to be available and then run again the check for user permissions.

The function enters a infinite loop when I add one line of code like this ->

## html

```
<SidebarNavTitle :key="item.key ? item.key : index" :name="item.name" 
:classes="item.class" :wrapper="item.wrapper"
                         :ref="item.name"
                         v-show="checkUserRole(item.disableFor, item) === true" />
```

## javascript

```
checkUserRole (disableFor, item) {
  if (disableFor && disableFor.length > 0) {
    // let roles = disableFor.slice(' ')
    if (this.getUser()) {
      if (disableFor.indexOf(this.getUser().role) != -1) {
        // console.log('show false')
        return false
      } else {
        // console.log('show true')
        return true
      }
    } else {
      console.error('Sidebarnav error. Not able to get loggedUser')
      // when I just add this line of code, the checkUserRole function, keeps getting called in an infinite loop, and doesn´t enter the setTimeout
      this.checkAgainElements.push([disableFor,item]) 
      // debugger
      if (this.checkAgain) {
         this.checkAgain = false
         // let _ = this
         setTimeout( () => {
           // _.checkAgainFunction()
         }, 7000)
      }
      return false
    }
  }
  return true
},

    asyncComputed:{
    asyncLoggedUser(){
      console.log('inside async user getter store sidebarnav')
      return this.$store.getters.user
    }
  },
  },
  data () {
    return {
      user: this.asyncLoggedUser,
      checkAgainElements: [],
      checkAgain: true,
      doubleCheck:true,
    }
  },

getUser() {
  if (!this.user) {
    this.user = JSON.parse(sessionStorage.getItem('loggedUser'))
  }
  return this.user
},
```

The actual result

[image: infinite loop]

I would expect the function to iterate through all the nav titles and enter the settimeout
What I could be missing here?

Comment: instead of timeout why not make the getUser() function return a promise?

Comment: Hi @Gowri, actually the user state is being managed inside vuex store is async, thus querying firebase, returning a promise. However, it happens that the rendering is checking for the user role, before the user info is actually available, because it take some time to update the vuex state. That´s why I´m using sessionStorage, to cache user profile locally... Make sense?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

So the solution was pretty simple... actually was just about to add in the v-show directive to check for the user object to be available as the first condition, then if available run the checkUserRole function, like this  `v-show="user && checkUserRole(item)"`.